# how to bring the box layout to the top in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I have written a .kv code which I expect to show the boxLayout on the top of the screen, but when I execute it no picture is set on the background and the boxLayout is created at the bottom.

How can I fix this so that the box layout is at the top and shows a picture in the background.

Note: The path of the picture is correct.

here is .kv code

```
<ScreenOne>:
    id: main_win    
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: 10
    space_x: self.size[0]/3
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: "/home/kiran/Desktop/Kivy-Screen/bg-03.2.jpg"

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0.06,0.75,0.7,0.8)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        Label:
            text: "Lend A Hand"
            bold: True



<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager

    screen_one: screen_one


    #instances of each screen
    ScreenOne:
        id: screen_one
        name: 'screen1'
        manager: screen_manager
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]..

Comment: I have altered the code to be as minimal as possible. @noEmbryo

Comment: The code in your example does not run. If I can not execute it, how should I know what's wrong with it? It has to be something that I can run in my system..